# How to build static libqsqlpsql.so in Qt in Ubuntu

Tags: qt, postgresql, build, driver

friend!
Please, help me. I am confused and sad. Darkness is embracing me and you, my friends, are the only hope I have.
I have installed qt in Ubuntu 10.10 using aptitude. 
Then I have installed libqt4-sql-psql. Now I have *.so files in qt's directory /usr/lib/qt4/plugins/sqldrivers.
Directory contains now 3 files actually.
$ ls -l

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 47048 2011-03-29 12:11 libqsqlite.so

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 63668 2011-03-29 12:11 libqsqlmysql.so

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 71844 2011-03-29 12:11 libqsqlpsql.so

There is no psql.pro or anything I can use to qmake this all. 
How can I build driver and use to work with postgres.
What should I do?

Maybe it is a dummy's question... sorry

Answer (score 1):

You have the file you need:

/usr/lib/qt4/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlpsql.so

this should allow you to use the driver. You can check which drivers are available using QSqlDatabase::drivers.